# How to make tags appear dynamically on a web page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, materialize

How to get the content of a selected checkbox and display it as a tag? (as displayed in E-commerce websites when a filter is selected)

I want to display the selected checkbox as a tag (Ex. Materialize CSS Chips)

Comment: can you explain more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the tags, add div element and give an id to the element to refer it later:

```
<div id="chip_displayed"></div>
```

Now, when a checkbox is selected, call the function to read the selected value.

```
$(document.body).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(){
    display();
});
```

display() will read the 'id' of the selected values and get 'name' parameter and add that to the Materialize CSS to display as a tag.

```
function display()
{
    document.getElementById("chip_displayed").innerHTML = "";

    var checked_ids = $('input:checkbox').filter(":checked").map(function () {
        return this.id;
    }).get();

    for(var i=0; checked_ids[i] ;i++)
    {
        var name = $('#'+checked_ids[i]).attr('name');
        document.getElementById("chip_displayed").innerHTML += "<div class='chip teal lighten-3' id='chip1'>"+name+"<i class='material-icons chip_close' id='close_chip1'>close</i></div>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Materialize Tags is a modern jQuery plugin used to create a nice-looking Material Design styled tag manager using Materialize framework.You can use it.check [here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Material-Design-Tags-Input-Plugin-with-jQuery-Materialize-Tags.html)